# How to make an animation to draw a triangle every second on canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, setinterval

I am learning javascript on the site [mdn Drawing graphics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Drawing_graphics) and its first example draws a lot of triangles on canvas when open the web

here's the original code the site provided:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('.myCanvas');
const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

ctx.translate(width/2, height/2);

function degToRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + (min);
}

let length = 250;
let moveOffset = 20;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${255-length},0,${255-length},0.9)`;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(moveOffset,moveOffset);
  ctx.lineTo(moveOffset+length,moveOffset);
  const triHeight = length/2 * Math.tan(degToRad(60));
  ctx.lineTo(moveOffset+(length/2),moveOffset+triHeight);
  ctx.lineTo(moveOffset,moveOffset);
  ctx.fill();

  length--;
  moveOffset+=0.7;
  ctx.rotate(degToRad(5));
}
```

and I want to modify the code to make it draw one triangle every second.
and Here's my code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(".myCanvas");
const width = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
const height = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

function degToRad(degrees) {
    return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;
}
  
let length = 250;
let moveOffset = 20;


let i=0;
let ani=0;
function animation(){
    if(!ani){
        ani=setInterval(draw,1000);
    }
}
function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${255 - length},0,${255 - length},0.9)`;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(moveOffset, moveOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(moveOffset + length, moveOffset);
    const triHeight = (length / 2) * Math.tan(degToRad(60));
    ctx.lineTo(moveOffset + length / 2, moveOffset + triHeight);
    ctx.lineTo(moveOffset, moveOffset);
    ctx.fill();

    length--;
    moveOffset += 0.7;
    ctx.rotate(degToRad(5));
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
animation();
```

the code can console "i(second)" every second, but there's nothing(except the black canvas) on the canvas.

But when I try the `window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)` method, the triangle don't appear one every second.
How can I fix this code to make it work as I wanted?
It's not necessary to use setInterval, I am free to use any method that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requestAnimationFrame` function is some sort of setTimeout that syncs with the browser frame rate. Here's a simple animation loop with all you need to know to make this work (see code comments).
This code will move the square every 1 second (approximatively).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

const canvasW = 500;
const canvasH = 500;

ctx.canvas.width = canvasW;
ctx.canvas.height = canvasH;

let timer = undefined;

const rectW = 50;
const rectH = 50;
const rectColor = "red";

let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function drawSquare(x, y) {
  ctx.fillStyle = rectColor;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, rectW, rectH);
}

function draw() {

  // Initial state
  if (timer === undefined) {
    timer = Date.now();
    drawSquare(x, y);
  }
  
  // State of the animation for subsequent frames
  if ((Date.now() - timer) >= 1000) {
    // We use >= 1000 (1sec) because the precision can be an issue
    timer = Date.now();
    x += 10;
    y += 10;
    
    // important: clear your canvas before drawing next frame
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    // Drawing
    drawSquare(x, y);
  }

  // Draw next frame if condition is truthy
  if (x < canvasW - rectW) {
    // Loop using recursion
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  
}

// Start animation loop and draw first frame
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: solid 1px black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but my problem is that I want to draw the triangle one at a time every second. I want to know how can I delay the code for 1 second in every loop. Can you modify your code to make your square move to the right 10px every second or show me how to delay for 1 second? thanks!!